# Why message digest should be kept secret?

Tags: cryptography

Why is it required to keep message digest secret? If A sends message M to B,then A will apply hash function to M and will get digest M'.

Now is there any requirement to encrypt M and M'? Assume that B is only concerned about message integrity?

I have learnt that Message digest needs to be kept secret but why so?If A is sending plain text without encryption then why should A cipher digest?

Comment: *"I have learnt that Message digest needs to be kept secret but why so?"* - please provide source for this and the context where keeping the digest secret is required according to this source.

Comment: I have read it in "data communication and networking forouzan 5th edition pdf"P-965. It says "The two pairs document/fingerprint and message/message digest are similar, with some
differences. The document and fingerprint are physically linked together; also, neither
needs to be kept secret. The message and message digest can be unlinked (or sent) separately
and, most importantly, the message digest needs to be kept secret. The message
digest is either kept secret in a safe place or encrypted if we need to send it through a
communications channel."

Comment: I cannot find such sentence in the 5th edition you refer to (do you really use the 5th?). But I can find on page 1098 a very similar sentence - only it does not say that the message digest must be kept secret but *" and, most importantly, the message digest needs to be __safe from change__."*

Comment: I am really sorry.I have both 4th and 5th edition.The above paragraph i quoted was from fourth edition.I dont know about changes in 5th edition.I will read the 1098 page once and verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the message is sent in the clear, then there's no reason to not send a digest in the clear... Except:

Using RSA to "sign" the message (to prove the identity of the person who sent it and the integrity of the message) involves encrypting the hash. This may be what you're reading about.

Since RSA is a key-pair algorithm, you can keep one key secret and make one key public. Therefore, if you encrypt the hash with your private key, then if somebody else decrypts it with your public key and that digest matches the message, then they can prove that you (the only one who has the private key) had to have written the message and nobody else has modified it in the meantime.

In this case, the point of encrypting the hash/digest isn't to hide it, but to use that encryption for proof of identity and integrity.

Comment: So digital signature is also a digest ?

Comment: Yes, a "digital signature" is an encrypted digest. This lets you verify that the digest ("hash") came from them, and that the message matches the hash, thereby the message could only come from them.